# How do I implement 3D A* Pathfinding in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, android, blender

I am using BDX (Blender with libgdx engine) to create my game. I am not sure on how to implement 3D path finding using A* search. I looked into gdx-ai, but that is for 2D.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the algorithm described on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)? What snag have got into?

Comment: I need to know how to construct navmesh, which I do not know how in libgdx (java)

Comment: Perhaps asking about this first would be more appropriate then. You might want to add what you've tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Having used A* path finding algorithms previously, my advice would be to take your Terrain, and break it down into smaller rectangles. Run a check to see if any of these rectangles co-inside with collidable entities. If they do, mark them as solid. From there, ensure each rectangle has a node, and continue as you would for calculating with 2D A*.

When it comes to Y:
This depends on how you have implemented the floor/terrain. Personally, I just set Y to be the height of the terrain at the current point. This works fine for me.

If you are also unfamiliar with A* path finding in 2D, there is a really good game dev series by [TheCherno](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheChernoProject) on YouTube that covers this which i'd advise looking at.

Hope that helps!